# FFT scale power spectrum

Tags: c++, image-processing, fft

I have problem to scale out power spectrum of image using FFT. The code is below

```
void spectrumFFT(Complex<double> *f, Complex<double> *output, int width, int height){

        Complex<double> *temp = new Complex<double>[width * height];
        Complex<double> *singleValue = new Complex<double>();            

        for(int j = 0; j < height; j++){
            for(int i = 0; i < width; i++){
                 singleValue = f[i + j * width];
                 Complex<double> tempSwap = singleValue->Mag();
                 // tempSwap assign Magnitude value from singleValue

                 temp[i + j * width] = tempSwap;                 
            }
         }
```

Let's say temp 1-D array is fill of magnitude value. What my problem is how to scale out min and max value of magnitude which range between [0 - 255).

Note : input *f is already calculated value of 2DFFT and *output value will be filled with min and max value of magnitude.

Any idea with programming?

Thank you,

Regards,
Ichiro

Comment: You have two memory leaks:  (1) You are initializing `singleValue` to point at a dynamically-created `Complex<double>`, and then immediately pointing it at something else.  (2) You are never doing anything with `temp`, and never `delete`-ing it.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Are you saying that you want to scale the data so that the minimum is always 0 and the maximum is always 255?

Comment: Guess we're just missing some more code (where `temp` is filled and later on deleted, there isn't a closing bracket for the function's scope).

Comment: Ignore above's mentioning of `temp` - misread one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't 100% clear, so I might be off and this might be not what you're looking for - I'll do it in general, ignoring the value range you might actually get or use.

Assuming you've got the absolute minimum and the absolute maximum value, `vmin` and `vmax` and you'd like to scale the whole range to [0; 255] you can do this that way:

```
// move the lower end to 0
double mod_add = -vmin;
double mod_mul = 255 / (vmax + mod_add);
```

Now, to rearrange one value to the range we calculated:

```
double scaled = (value + mod_add) * mod_mul;
```

`mod_add` will move negative numbers/values to the positive range (where the absolute minimum will become 0) and `mod_mul` will scale the whole range (from absolute minimum to absolute maximum) to fit into [0; 255]. Without negative values you're able to skip `mod_add` obviously. If you'd like to keep 0 in center (i.e. at 127) you'll have to skip `mod_add` and instead use the absolute maximum of `vmax` and `vmin` and scale that to 127 instead of 255.

---

On a side note, I think you could simplify your loop a lot, possibly saving some processing time (might not be possible depending on other code being there):

```
const unsigned int num = width * height;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    temp[i] = f[i]->Mag();
```

Also, as mentioned by Oli in the comments, you shouldn't assign any value to `singleValue` in the beginning, as it's overwritten later on anyway.

Comment: Hi Oli and Mario, Thank you for you advice and comment. Yes i want to scale between 0 to 255, so that within the range of data is in 8 bit. I am poor in C++ programming, it almost 11 years i haven't touch C++. Thank your for pointing out of memory leak. I am feeling of memory leaks in this application due to such coding. I will give result after test. Thank you

Comment: You're going to want to take the log of the magnitude of the FFT spectrum if you hope to see anything of interest otherwise you'll get a few points near 255 and the rest 0.

Comment: Hi Mario, it shows a single line, well it is not match 100% with demo application. What i did for find Min and Max value is create another loop and compare each value with temp[i] to find min and max value e.g 0 - 18866, after that i use your code and  create another  loop, i put calcuated scale value inside this loop and assigned value to the *output.  what i exactly want is "scaled power spectrum with value normalized to the range of [0, 255]"

Comment: Should get you what you want, just consider jeff7's comment regarding the logarithmic scaling, which might screw up value distribution.

Comment: Hi Jeff, Do you have any sample, how to do log of the magnitude of the FFT specturm? Thank you